# MessageShow in another class?

Tags: c#, class, object, instantiation

This is my first time trying to implement separate class into form class, rather than just having it all in the form class. How do I go about connecting the two? When the button is clicked, I wanted to be able to have it show the letter grade with MessageBox.Show.

Thanks.

**Form1.cs**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Grade Nested = new Grade();

    }
}
```

**Class.cs**

```
class Grade
{
    private int number;

    public int Number
    {
        get { return number; }

        set { number = value; }
    }

    public static int Nested(int grade)
    {

        if (grade >= 93)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("A");
        }

        else if (grade >= 90 && grade <= 92)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("A-");
        }

        else if (grade >= 87 && grade <= 89)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("B+");
        }

        else if (grade >= 83 && grade <= 86)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("B");
        }

        else if (grade >= 80 && grade <= 82)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("B-");
        }

        else if (grade >= 77 && grade <= 79)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("C+");
        }

        else if (grade >= 73 && grade <= 76)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("C");
        }

        else if (grade >= 70 && grade <= 72)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("C-");
        }

        else if (grade >= 67 && grade <= 69)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("D+");
        }

        else if (grade >= 63 && grade <= 66)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("D");
        }

        else if (grade >= 60 && grade <= 62)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("D-");
        }

        else if (grade <= 59)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("F");
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made the `Nested` method `static`, so you can just call it like this:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var grade = int.Parse(someTextBox.Text);
    Grade.Nested(grade);
}
```

I'm assuming the grade comes from a text box you have on the form, and I've skipped all validation and error handling.

---

Also, the `Number` property and field don't do anything in the code you have shown.

You might also find [Code Review.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) a good place to get feedback on your coding style.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm definitely bookmarking Code Review.SE!

Comment: @RustyShackleford Please note that CodeReview will not help you *write* code, like this answer. It is for already working code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of return type `int`. Return type `string` will be more proper, you don't need to repeat `MessageBox.Show()` again and again. Or just make it `void`.

```
public static string Nested(int grade)
        {
            if (grade >= 93)
            {
                return "A";
            }
....
```

and `MessageBox` part should be like this,

```
string test =  Nested.Nested(number);
MessageBox.Show(test);
```

Hope helps,